# Exception thrown using Monitor.Exit

Tags: c#, clr

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this exception.
Here's the code I'm running and things I've tried.

```
public static Boolean IsRunning = false;

public static void Process()
{
    Boolean lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(IsRunning, ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            // Run code
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.Log(); }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(IsRunning);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I'm getting the exception thrown at the `Monitor.Exit(IsRunning);` line which is weird since I'm only running that line of code if the monitor was successful to obtain a lock for the `IsRunning` object. Any clue of what might be causing this exception to be thrown?

The exception being thrown is Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Comment: You haven't specified what exception is being thrown.

Comment: @PhonicUK it is no need to specify the type of an exception. The type of the IsRunning is System.Boolean, so it is obviously SynchronizationLockException :)

Answer (score 4):

Well... the property `IsRunning` is of type `System.Boolean` which is the value type or structure. You can set lock only on the instance of a reference type.

Here you can read about `Monitor` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor?view=netcore-3.1

Here you can read about value and reference types: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type

When you pass an instance of the value type to the method as a `System.Object` or via an interface the boxing allocation occurs.

What is it?

CLR allocates memory, then it copies the value of the passed instance to the heap and really passes the reference to the allocated object into the called method.
So, when you call `Enter` the CLR allocates a new object and passes it's reference to the method. When you call `Exit` it allocates one more new object and it is *another* object. So the current thread is not holding lock on it. This is the reason why an exception was thrown.

You can read about boxing and unboxing here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#:~:text=Boxing%20is%20the%20process%20of,value%20type%20from%20the%20object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#:%7E:text=Boxing%20is%20the%20process%20of,value%20type%20from%20the%20object).

Answer (score 1):

Serafim Prozorov has already explained the problem here, but: you're making your own life hard. In the scenario shown, you're not using any timeout etc, which means that your code is semantically identical to using `lock`:

```cs
try
{
    lock (IsRunning)
    {
        // Run code 
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { e.Log(); }
```

The reason that this is *relevant* is that the above code **does not compile**; it says:

> CS0185    'bool' is not a reference type as required by the lock statement

which would have stopped you from making this mistake.

There's other scenarios it spots too, that using `Monitor` directly *does not* spot, for example `await` (CS1996, Cannot await in the body of a lock statement).

---

Note also that neither `Monitor` or `lock` is going to *change* your `bool` to record that it is running. There are two common ways of doing that:

1. have the synchronization and "am I doing something?" separate, and update the latter as needed
2. use an `int` field, and use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to change it between 0 and 1; for example: `if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref active, 1, 0) == 0)` moves from inactive (`0`) to active (`0`) **if and only if** it was inactive, with the expression (including the `==0`) returning `true` in that case, or `false` otherwise (i.e. it was already active)